# fedora [Errno 28] No space left on device: '/var/cache/dnf/metadata_lock.pid' // but space are huge

Tags: fedora, dnf

Here is the error message :

```
[root@h2g2w dnf]# dnf update
[Errno 28] No space left on device: '/var/cache/dnf/metadata_lock.pid'
[root@h2g2w dnf]#
```

here are partitions informations :

```
[root@h2g2w dnf]# df -h | sort -nk5
devtmpfs                             7,8G       0  7,8G   0% /dev
Sys. de fichiers                   Taille Utilisé Dispo Uti% Monté sur
tmpfs                                1,6G       0  1,6G   0% /run/user/0
tmpfs                                7,8G       0  7,8G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/mapper/VGSYS-tmp                4,4G     14M  4,2G   1% /tmp
/dev/mapper/VGSYS-yum                3,9G     17M  3,7G   1% /var/lib/yum
tmpfs                                1,6G    116K  1,6G   1% /run/user/1000
tmpfs                                7,8G    1,8M  7,8G   1% /run
tmpfs                                7,8G     52M  7,8G   1% /dev/shm
/dev/mapper/VGSYS-dnf                3,9G     63M  3,6G   2% /var/lib/dnf
/dev/mapper/VGSYS-docker              20G    625M   18G   4% /var/lib/docker
/dev/mapper/VGSYS-games              506M     41M  466M   8% /usr/games
/dev/mapper/VGSYS-log                4,4G    651M  3,6G  16% /var/log
/dev/mapper/VGSYS-var                7,4G    3,5G  3,6G  50% /var
/dev/mapper/VGSYS-psql               240M    140M   84M  63% /var/lib/pgsql
/dev/mapper/VGSYS-bckp               170G    112G   59G  66% /home/backup
/dev/mapper/VGSYS-opt                 34G     21G   12G  66% /opt
/dev/mapper/VGSYS-usr                 13G    8,2G  4,0G  68% /usr
/dev/mapper/VGSYS-root               1,5G    962M  424M  70% /
/dev/mapper/VGSYS-timeshiftbackups   123G     85G   32G  73% /run/media/root/ece7ac25-cd58-4f61-a201-09849ea3a81f
/dev/mapper/VGSYS-share               13G    9,2G  3,0G  76% /usr/share
/dev/sda1                            248M    186M   50M  80% /boot
/dev/mapper/vgf-francois             155G    142G  4,7G  97% /home/francois
[root@h2g2w dnf]#
```

so it cannot be a space issue ; so I checked the specific one :

```
[root@h2g2w dnf]# df -h .
Sys. de fichiers      Taille Utilisé Dispo Uti% Monté sur
/dev/mapper/VGSYS-var   7,4G    3,5G  3,6G  50% /var
[root@h2g2w dnf]#
```

there are not openned file here :

```
root@h2g2w dnf]# lsof | grep /var/cache/dnf/metadata_lock.pid
[root@h2g2w dnf]#
```

so what to do then ? is it safe to clean metadata & retry ?

Comment: Oh ...very good idea... I didn't thought about it.... & of course here is the issue.... /var 100% while checking df -i ....  Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You’ve probably run out of free inodes; use `df -i` to check.

Comment: Thanks a lot , I increased partition size (lvm) & I looked on what files to be moved or deleted  :) this solved the issue.